# Zend_ProgressBar

Tags: zend-framework

Anyone have the idea to implement Zend_ProgressBar?  If don't mind please write a sample code.

Comment: And did you find the solution in the manual i had linked?

Comment: i didn't get the idea .. how we show the progress bar in phtml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhm,

I've typed a standard search query on google:  "Using Zend progressbar" and got this nice page that will help you out ;).

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.progressbar.introduction.html